# Azure Powershell - Script to obtain VM info across subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to run a script that will connect to each subscription, and pull the

```
$azureSubs = Get-AzureRMSubscription
$azureSubs | ForEach-Object {Select-AzureRMSubscription $_ | Out-Null; Get-AzureRMVM | select resourcegroupname, name, licensetype -WarningAction SilentlyContinue}
```

This works, BUT I'd like to add two more pieces of information:  the "OSType" and "VMSize"

If I do a GET-AZURERMVM, in the table for that subscription that the command is run in, the two pieces of information I need are there:  VmSize and OsType

However, when I try to add them to the query, the columns are blank.
I believe the VmSize is in the HardwareProfile, and OsType is in the OsProfile,  as if I run a "Get-AzureRMVM -name (name) -resourcegroupname (RGname)", then it shows "Hardware Profile: VMSize" and "OSProfile: ComputerName, AdminUsername windowsConfiguration, Secrets"

Ultimate goal is to get the script that will, for each subscription, print results like:

```
ResourceGroupName  |  Name | License Type | VMSize | OS Type
TEST_RG | Test_VM | Windows_Server | DS3_v2 | Windows
Test_RG | Test_VM2 |     |  DS3_v2 | Linux
```

etc.

Thankful for any help; sorry for such a noob question.  Have spent so much time trying to figure this out...

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would work. 
What you were missing mainly was [calculated properties](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/). 
This is what allow you to perform a select of custom property.

Some notes:

In your code, you used `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue` on the Select statement. You need to put it on the `Get-AzureRMVM` CmdLet instead.

This is my opinion but unless you are writing one-liners on purposes, try aerating your code more. It will make it way easier to read, debug and maintain.

This is the code you wrote, modified  to include the calculated properties and with the WarningAction parameter set to `Get-AzureRMVM` instead of the `Select` statement.

```
$azureSubs = Get-AzureRMSubscription
$Vms = $azureSubs | ForEach-Object {Select-AzureRMSubscription $_ | Out-Null; Get-AzureRMVM -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | select resourcegroupname, name, licensetype,  @{Name="VMSize";Expression={$_.HardwareProfile.VmSize}},@{Name="OsType";Expression={$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType}}}
$Vms | ft
```

The same thing, with some progress indication  without forcing everything on one line.

```
$azureSubs = Get-AzureRMSubscription
$Vms = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]'
ForEach ($sub in $azureSubs) {
    Select-AzureRMSubscription $sub | Out-Null  
    Write-Host "Processing Subscription $($sub.Name)".PadRight(50,' ') -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline
    [PsObject[]]$items = Get-AzureRMVM -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | 
        select resourcegroupname,
           name, 
           licensetype,
            @{Name="VMSize";Expression={$_.HardwareProfile.VmSize}}, 
            @{Name="OsType";Expression={$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType}}

        Write-Host "($($items.count) retrieved)"
        if ($items -ne $null) {
            $vms.AddRange($items)
        }
}


$vms | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this on the `select` side

`select resourcegroupname, name, licensetype, @{Name="VMSize";Expression={$_.HardwareProfile.VmSize}}, @{Name="OsType";Expression={$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType}}`